# "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in"

Tags: php, sql, database

The following code is getting the error message displayed in the title:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$rep_id       = $row['Report_ID'];
$rep_title    = $row['Report_Title'];
$rep_keywords = $row['Report_Keywords'];
$rep_cat      = $row['Report_Category_Subs'];
$rep_status   = $row['Report_Private'];
```

Any Ideas why this may be the case?

Thanks

Edit: Here is the code below the while

```
if ($name == $_SESSION['user']['User_ID'] || isAdmin()) {
// User is retrieving their own data or admin is retrieving data
global $conn;

$name = $conn->real_escape_string($name);
$sql = 
"SELECT * 
FROM reports 
WHERE User_ID = '".$name."'
ORDER BY Report_ID DESC
LIMIT 500;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$tbl  = '<form action="myreports.php" method="post" id="modify">
<select name="choice">
<option value="">--Select Bulk Option--</option>
<option value="reverse-status">Change Public Status</option>
<option value="change-cats">Change Categories/Keywords</option>
<option value="delete">Delete Reports</option>
</select>
<input class="formbutton" id="sub" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br/>

<table class="table">';
$tbl .= '<tr>  <th class="no-bg"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="left" />                                                                        
</th>  <th>ID</th>  <th>Title</th>  <th>Keywords</th>  <th>Category</th>    
<th>Public</th></tr>';
```

Comment: can you please post the code before the while loop? the exeption message is a clue that something went wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words "`$result` doesn't contain what you think it **does**". I think that your problem is that `$result` is probably returning **false**. That means that your query has failed.

Try to `var_dump($result)` and see if it is **false**.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because of `$result`. Probably the `$result` has **false** value due to the query which failed. You need to give more code make my answer more specfic but firstly check the query.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases errors like this occur because you do not check if query you execured returned any data set you can work on, or (most likely) your query **failed** so `$result` is not an object, hence the error message.